# WAMP Apache httpd.conf file lacking content

Tags: apache, web, server, wamp

My httpd.conf file is missing these lines:

`Order Deny,Allow`

`Deny from all`

So I cant make my website public. Is there another way of doing so or is that option called something else and I'm just looking at an outdated guide?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer? And what version of Apache are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 3.1.0